# Exporting a report with multiple sheets from JasperServer to Excel

Tags: excel, jasper-reports, export, jasperserver

I created a report using iReport and set the 'One Page per Sheet' option to true in the Excel Export parameters, this generates a report in iReport with multiple sheets.

I then loaded the report onto JasperServer, the report's output appears on multiple pages, exporting the report to Excel results in the data appearing on one sheet instead of multiple sheets.

Is there a way or an option that can be set so that the data appears on multiple sheets when exported from JasperServer?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the ***`net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.one.page.per.sheet`*** property.

The information about this property is [here](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/config.reference.html#net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.one.page.per.sheet).

- The property can be added to the **`jasperreports.properties`** file (in *jasperserver\WEB-INF\classes* folder):

```sh
net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.one.page.per.sheet=true
```

- The property can be added to the report template (jrxml file)

The sample:

```xml
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" ...>
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.one.page.per.sheet" value="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just remove `IS_ONE_PAGE_PER_SHEET`.Its working 100% .

```
exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_ONE_PAGE_PER_SHEET, Boolean.FALSE);
```

Just remove this line of coding from your code.